# Error while executing make makeFile in Windows PowerShell

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make file from tool `bmp2glcd`, I have installed `make` using `Windows PowerShell` via `chocolatey`, but when I try to `make` the `makeFile`, It gives me the error:

`make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified. make: *** [makefile:23: EasyBMP.o] Error 2`.
The Following is the code of makeFile:

````
#  BMP2GLCD - BMP to GLCD image makefile
#                       
#       Author: Sami Varjo 
# file creatd : 31.7.2008
#      version: 1.0
#                                                
#   License: GPL which can be found at
#        http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt
#                                                
# description: makefile for compiling bmp2glcd program with the EasyBMP library. 
#

CC = g++
BILLFLGS = -Wformat=2
CFLAGS = $(BILLFLGS) -O3 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -funroll-all-loops -s
CINC = -I ./EasyBMP/

bmp2glcd: EasyBMP.o bmp2glcd.o 
    g++ $(CFLAGS) EasyBMP.o bmp2glcd.o -o bmp2glcd

EasyBMP.o: EasyBMP/EasyBMP.cpp EasyBMP/EasyBMP*.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c EasyBMP/EasyBMP.cpp

bmp2glcd.o: bmp2glcd.cpp
    g++ $(CINC) -c bmp2glcd.cpp

clean: 
    rm -f bmp2glcd
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~ \#*\#```

I don't know where I am doing mistake.
````

Comment: At first guess I'd say you installed make but you didn't install a compiler, so `g++` is not available to compile your code.

Comment: @MadScientist, How to install g++ in Windows PowerShell?

Comment: No idea; I don't do Windows.  But presumably Google can help you.

Comment: can you show your directory structure?